# Problemas Con Condición en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una condición con dos funciones las cuales son bool, en caso de que ambas sean verdadero debería pasar a hacer la acción que se programó en el if , pero esta acción no la respeta, ya que cuando apenas está empezando una de las funciones ya me esta pasando a la acción que debe de realizar en caso de que sean verdaderas las dos.
La parte de actualizar usuario si me lo hace , hasta ahí todo ok, pero después de que actualizo la información del usuario entra al if en caso de que ambas [**EnviaDatosAActualizar_RA() y EnviaDatosAActualizar_CA()**] hayan sido verdaderas, procederá a redirigir al index de la lista de usuarios.

El problema viene cuando apenas esta ejecutando una función ya se esta redirigiendo a la pagina donde están la lista de usuarios. hay alguna manera de decirle que espera y que no pase al siguiente proceso sin que haya terminado el antecesor , no se si tenga mal la sintaxis de mis funciones me podrían ayudar en como solucionar este problema.
**Este es mi código:**

```js
 <!--ACTUALIZAR-->
    <script>
        $("#Actualizar").click(function () {
            if (ValidaCampos()) {
                $('#fader').css('display', 'block');
                var EnviaDatos =
                {

                    "u.USERID": $('#UserID').val(),
                    "u.NOMBRE": $('#nombre').val(),
                    "u.APELLIDO": $('#apellido').val(),
                    "u.USEREMAIL": $('#UserMail').val(),
                    "u.PASSWORD": $('#Password').val(),
                    "u.ACTIVO": $("#ChbUsuarioActivo").is(':checked') ? "Y" : "N",
                    "u.PERFILID": $('#lPerfilId').val(),
                    "u.TIPO_USUARIO": $("#ChbUsuarioInterno").is(':checked') ? "I" : "E",


                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../Account/ActualizaUsuario',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(EnviaDatos),
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            if (EnviaDatosAActualizar_RA() && EnviaDatosAActualizar_CA()) {
                                $('#fader').css('display', 'none');
                                //alert(response.responseText);
                                window.location = "../Account/Index";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#fader').css('display', 'none');

                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        $('#fader').css('display', 'none');
                        alert('Ocurrio un Error Inesperado.' + xhr);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
       
    </script>
 <!--CATH CHECK AND UNCHECK ROL ACCESO-->
    <script>
        var ra = new Array();

        $(document).on('change', '#ContenedorCHB input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
            var r_a = {};
            var Id_usuario = $('#UserID').val();
            if (this.checked) {

                r_a.ID = $(this).attr("id");
                r_a.ACTIVO = "Y";
                r_a.ID_USUARIO = Id_usuario;
                ra.push(r_a);
                //alert("Esta desactivado: " + EnviaDatos + '\n\n');
            }
            else {

                r_a.ID = $(this).attr("id");
                r_a.ACTIVO = "N";
                r_a.ID_USUARIO = Id_usuario;
                ra.push(r_a);
                //alert("Esta desactivado: " + EnviaDatos + '\n\n');
            };
            //alert(EnviaDatos[0]);
            //if (this.id == "nacional") {
            //    if (this.checked) $('#id_nacional').val(this.value);
            //    else $('#id_nacional').val("");
            //}

        });
        function EnviaDatosAActualizar_RA() {
            var ok = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: '../Account/ActualizaRolChB',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(ra),
                success: function (response) {
                    //alert(response.responseText);
                    ok = true;
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    $('#fader').css('display', 'none');
                    alert('Ocurrio un Error Inesperado.');
                    ok = false;
                   
                }
            })
            return ok;
        };
    </script>

    <!--CATH CHECK AND UNCHECK CAT ACCESO-->
    <script>
        var ca = new Array();

        $(document).on('change', '#ContenedorCHB_1 input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
            var c_a = {};
            var Id_usuario = $('#UserID').val();
            if (this.checked) {
                //alert("Esta activado: " + $('#UserID').val());
                c_a.ID = $(this).attr("id");
                c_a.ACTIVO = "Y";
                c_a.ID_USUARIO = Id_usuario;
                ca.push(c_a);
                //alert("Esta desactivado: " + EnviaDatos + '\n\n');
            }
            else {
                //alert("Esta desactivado: " + $('#UserID').val());
                c_a.ID = $(this).attr("id");
                c_a.ACTIVO = "N";
                c_a.ID_USUARIO = Id_usuario;
                ca.push(c_a);
                //alert("Esta desactivado: " + EnviaDatos + '\n\n');
            };
            //alert(EnviaDatos[0]);
            //if (this.id == "nacional") {
            //    if (this.checked) $('#id_nacional').val(this.value);
            //    else $('#id_nacional').val("");
            //}

        });

        function EnviaDatosAActualizar_CA() {
            var ok = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: '../Account/ActualizaAccesosChB',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(ca),
                success: function (response) {
                    //alert(response.responseText);
                    ok = true;
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    $('#fader').css('display', 'none');
                    ok = false;
                    alert('Ocurrio un Error Inesperado.');
                }
            })
            return ok;
        };
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Es que yo creo que es porqué en las funciones "EnviaDatosAActualizar_RA()" y "EnviaDatosAActualizar_CA()" no estás devolviendo el estado de la variable "ok", sino que estás asignando un valor y ya. Prueba de poner "return true" o "return false" según convenga (no hace falta que declares ninguna variable "ok")

Comment: agrega esto a tu `ajax`   cache: false,  async: false,

Comment: hola @FerranMuñoz si lo intente pero me pone la funcion como void en vez de bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

son dos funciones asincronas puedes declarar como sicronas y esperar 
su ejecucion, aqui las modificaciones ,

```js
async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async  function funcionA()
{
  var resultado=false;
  await delay(2000).then(function(){resultado=true});
   console.log('fin funcion A, resultado:' +resultado );
  return resultado;
}

async  function funcionB()
{
  var resultado=false;
  await delay(3000).then(function(){resultado=true});
  console.log('fin funcion B, resultado:' +resultado );
  return resultado;
}


async function funcionAyB()
{
console.log('espera 5 seg para ver resultado')
  var resA=await funcionA();
  var resB= await funcionB();

 console.log('resultado logico:');
 console.log(resA && resB);
  
}

//llamando la funcion
funcionAyB();
```

```
//declaracion de tu funcion
async function EnviaDatosAActualizar_RA() {

 await $.ajax(    //espera de ejecuciondel llamado a servidor

      );

}

// segunda funcion
async  function EnviaDatosAActualizar_CA() {
      await $.ajax(    //espera de ejecuciondel llamado a servidor

      );

}

........
//ahora para el llamado y comprobacion de tu if
if (response.success) {
var resDatosRA= EnviaDatosAActualizar_RA();
var resDatosCA= EnviaDatosAActualizar_CA();
                            if (resDatosRA && resDatosCA) {
                                $('#fader').css('display', 'none');

.....
```